# EasyAdmin 3 create custom field

Tags: forms, autocomplete, symfony4, symfony-forms, easyadmin

I'd like to create custom autocomplete field with externe api call.
I'm using doc [Create custom fields](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/fields.html#creating-custom-fields)

But my template is not used.

```
public static function new(string $propertyName, ?string $label = null): self
{
    return (new self())
        ->setProperty($propertyName)
        ->setLabel($label)
        // this template is used in 'index' and 'detail' pages
        ->setTemplatePath('admin/field/address.html.twig')
        // this is used in 'edit' and 'new' pages to edit the field contents
        // you can use your own form types too
        ->setFormType(TextType::class)
        ->addCssClass('field-address')
        // these methods allow to define the web assets loaded when the
        // field is displayed in any CRUD page (index/detail/edit/new)
        ->addCssFiles('js/admin/field-address.css')
        ->addJsFiles('js/admin/field-address.js')
        ;
}
```

I've no error.
I create template in : /templates/admin/field

Anyone has an idea ?

Comment: It's ok, it works. But I'd like to modify field template in edit page

Comment: You need to modify the form template for that